# Query a mongodb timeseries collection, and get the time difference between datapoints

Tags: mongodb

Let's say we have a MongoDB time-series collection, for now without a meta field.

```js
const granularity = "second";
const expireAfterSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

createCollection("test", {
    timeseries: {
        timeField: "_createdAt",
        //metaField: "metadata",
        granularity,
    },
    expireAfterSeconds,
});
```

We want to know the time between the considered and the previous document.
Since the collection has no meta field, we can not modify the document and add a second timestamp afterward.

We can run the following aggregation pipline:

```js
collection("test").aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      _createdAt: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "test",
      let: { current_timestamp: "$_createdAt" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                { $eq: ["$_createdAt", "$$current_timestamp"] },
                { $lt: ["$_createdAt", "$$current_timestamp"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            _createdAt: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 2
        }
      ],
      as: "matched_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      prev_doc: { $arrayElemAt: ["$matched_docs", 1] },
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      _deltaTms: {
        $subtract: ["$_createdAt", "$prev_doc._createdAt"]
      },
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      matched_docs: 0,
      prev_doc: 0,
    }
  }
]).toArray();
```

This solution extends the document with the _deltaTms field, which is the time delta between the last document in milliseconds.

I wonder if this is the right solution, it looks slightly overcomplicated.
Would it be more efficient in terms of query speed to add a meta field, and rather modify the last document by adding a timestamp, and using a meta field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mongodb version 5.0 you can use `$setWindowFields` for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {_createdAt: 1},
      output: {prev: {
          $first: "$_createdAt",
          window: {documents: [-1, 0]}
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {
      _deltaTms: {$subtract: ["$_createdAt", "$prev"]},
      prev: "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/px8wYNxafhh)

Comment: Thank you very much. The $lookup solution took over 10 seconds on 4000 records, and this solution returns results instantly.